problem in getting cookies in new chromium.connectOverCDP instance
I'm starting my main browser like this :
const options = {
    headless: true,
    args: [
        `--ignore-certificate-errors`,
        `--remote-debugging-port=${port}`
    ]
};
const browser = await chromium.launch(options);
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.context().newCDPSession(page);
let context = page.context();
if (fs.existsSync(storageStatePath)) { 
    const { cookies } = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(storageStatePath));
    await context.addCookies(cookies);
}

and in other file im trying to use logged in cookies:
const browser = await chromium.connectOverCDP('http://127.0.0.1:9999/');
const cookies = (await browser.contexts()[0].cookies());
console.log(cookies);

but it's return empty , even i tried connect() method but it's worse and contexts() are empty!
and when i'm taking screenshot form first page of current context it's blank white page!
i'm trying to keep login my browser with other file and use other file as service provider with express
